# How to retrieve comments from WordPress posts in a given taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to write some code in my plugin which displays only comments for posts which have a specific value set for a custom taxonomy. My set up is:
Custom post type - Object
Custom taxonomy - Sources
Example value - ABC Museum

Commenting is enabled for Objects
I can retrieve comments by user and by each custom post

I have tried:

```
$meta_query = array('key' => 'sources',  'value' => 'ABC Museum');
$args = array(
    'number' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'Object',
    'meta_query' => array($meta_query)
);
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );
```

but this returns an empty array. Is this just a silly syntax error on my part, or have I misunderstood the use of meta_query and it won't work for custom taxonomies and custom post types?

Looking at http://pippinsplugins.com/querying-comments-with-wp_comment_query-and-meta-query-in-3-5/ I think it may be the latter - the meta has to be related to the comment, not teh post that it was added to, is that correct? Unfortunately http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments is rather thin on details and examples!

Thanks

Comment: have you looked into **wp_list_comments** ?? - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments - also looking at **WP_Comment_Query** in the codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query -

Answer (score 0):

The meta_key value needs to be attached to comment itself [Check Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta). WP Comment Query will return nothing if you pull comments based on meta value of their respective posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is you are using `post_type` instead of `type` which is the difference between a comment query and a normal post query in WordPress. If you want to have a previous array to filter out which types of posts (or custom posts) to pull from, that needs to be e.g. **$taxonomy_array** which you can associate with the `post__in` option...

```
$tax_id = get_queried_object_id(); // current taxonomy ID number
$taxonomy_array = get_posts( array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'post_type' => 'movies',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'studio',
            'terms' => $tax_id
        )
    )
) );

$args = array(
    'post__in' => $taxonomy_array,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'type' => 'comment',
    'status' => 'approve',
    'parent' => 0
);
                        
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );
```